# mouse drawing does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I try to convert this [code](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Demo/tkinter/guido/paint.py) which allows the user to draw after mouse button press to an object oriented one:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Test:
   def __init__(self):
       self.b1="up"
       self.xold=None
       self.yold=None
   def test(self,obj):
       self.drawingArea=Canvas(obj)
       self.drawingArea.pack() 
       self.drawingArea.bind("<Motion>",self.motion)
       self.drawingArea.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",self.b1down)
       self.drawingArea.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",self.b1up)
   def motion(self,event):
       self.b1="down"
   def b1up(self,event):
       self.b1="up"
       self.xold=None
       self.yold=None
   def b1down(self,event):
      if self.b1=="down":
           if self.xold is not None and self.yold is not None:
               event.widget.create_line(self.xold,self.yold,event.x,event.y,smooth=TRUE)
           self.xold=event.x
           self.yold=event.y


if __name__=="__main__":
   root=Tk()
   root.wm_title("Test")
   v=Test()
   v.test(root)
   root.mainloop()
```

No error/warning is fired, however nothing happens on the canvas. What am I missing? Obviously the condition `if self.xold is not None and self.yold is not None:` is never satified.

Comment: Have you tried putting in some `print`s to see what's happening?

Comment: @jonrsharpe when I print `self.xold` and `self.yold` in `b1dowbn()` I surprisingly get the correspondant coordinates

Comment: Then are you sure it's that `if`, and not `if self.b1 == 'down'`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for your concern, the man below said i switched 2 functions and that was my problem indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You switched the `motion` and `b1down` functions. On the `<ButtonPress-1>` event the flag `self.b1="down"` should be set and on the `<Motion>` you make the drawing:

```
def b1down(self, event):
    self.b1 = "down"

def motion(self, event):
    if self.b1 == "down":
        if self.xold is not None and self.yold is not None:
            event.widget.create_line(self.xold, self.yold, event.x, event.y, smooth=TRUE)
        self.xold = event.x
        self.yold = event.y
```

Comment: I'm sorry to disturb you with an other question one day after your accurate and accepted answer. I just wonder if you have an idea why the line is drawn whereas the condition `if self.xold is not None and self.yold is not None:` is never satisfied ?

Comment: Those two variables are just `None` at the beginning of the drawing. After the callback `motion`is called the first time, they are always set to the previous pointer position. Personally I would set `self.xold` and `self.yold` in the `b1down` function, but it is working both ways.